# How to downgrade sqlite3 that comes with Python and Django

Tags: sqlite, django, downgrade

So I am stuck in this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637182/django-no-such-table-main-auth-user-old

I can't upgrade Django because many other applications are connected to it using version 2.1. The only approach is to edit the sqlite3. Currently, I am using SQLITE3 3.26.0 and I want to downgrade to 2.5.1. How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you create a virtual environment for your new application with a newer version of Django? Is it an option?

Answer (score 0):

> I can't upgrade Django because many other applications are connected to it using version 2.1. [...] Currently, I am using SQLite 3.26.0 and I want to downgrade to 2.5.1. How can I do this?

You don't.

1. Back up a dump. Try to have it in text mode.
2. Build SQLite 2 from sources.
3. Restore the dump from SQLite 2. Fail to.

   1. Edit awk scripts to fix your issues or use a data base
      migration software.
   2. Try again to restore, if it fails, go back to 3.1.
4. Done.

Comment: Thanks @John. However, I am new here. Could you please elaborate just a bit more on each step. Highly appreciated.

Comment: We're all new to something. I feel your pain.

Comment: I think what @john means is that you have to take a text dump of your database. There will be incompatibilities. Therefore you use *nix text processing tools like `sed` or `awk` to make changes to your dump to make it compatible with SQLite 2.1. You can see an example [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127229/mysql-workbench-data-import-csv/127235#127235) or [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207132/dbms-to-load-multiple-types-of-dump-files/207180#207180).